# Ошибка invoking method при запуске jar

Tags: java, javafx, maven, jar, httpclient

Возникла проблема при сборке проекта в IntelliJ IDEA. Использовал Maven и JavaFX.

Суть программы считать данные с поля ввода текста, оправить на сервер запрос(поверка номера) и в случае, если номер есть в бд, идет переход на след. сцену.

При тестировании в IntelliJ IDEA все работает как часы, но при попытке запустить jar появляется ошибка:

> Error invoking method

Разбираясь с проблемой пришел к тому, что если убрать код метода запроса на сервер (метод `aurorization()`), jar запускается и производится переход к след. сцене, но если "включить" метод и даже если не использовать метод, возникает ошибка:

> Error invoking method

Для удобства код обработки нажатия кнопки и код отправки запроса на сервер представлены в контроллере.

MainApp

```
package com.devcolibri.mavenjavafxapp;

public class MainApp extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    String fxmlFile = "/fxml/login.fxml";
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    Parent root = loader.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream(fxmlFile));
    stage.setTitle("YouDelivery");
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.getIcons().add(new Image("/ic/YD-256.png"));
    stage.show();
    }
}
```

Контроллер

```
package com.devcolibri.mavenjavafxapp.controllers;

public class LoginControllerFX {

    @FXML
    private TextField edLogin;


    public void logIn(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

        Stage stageIn = (Stage) 
        ((Node)actionEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        String login = edLogin.getText();
        Resp authorization = aurorization(login, "1");

        if(true){
            try {
                FXMLLoader loader = new 
                FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/start_order.fxml"));
                Parent root = loader.load();
                stageIn.setScene(new Scene(root, 850, 450));
                stageIn.show();

            }  catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else
            showAlertError("Ошибка авторизации!");
    }

    private void showAlertError(String text) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setTitle("Авторизация");
        alert.setHeaderText(null);
        alert.setContentText(text);
        alert.showAndWait();
    }


    private Resp aurorization(String login, String pass) { // Метод авторизации
        Gson GSON = new Gson();
        String appKey = "c312b5a7b1794220a85b89079250e64e";
        String cliKey = "aec9813472954766897c74a55815d4e1";
        final String j =
            "{\n" +
            "\"app\":\"" + appKey + "\",\n" +
            "\"cli\":\"" + cliKey + "\",\n" +
            "\"email\":\"" + login + "\",\n" +
            "\"password\":\"1\"\n" +
            "}";

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        String url = "https://api.scorocode.ru/api/v1/login";
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.addHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");

        StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(j, org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        httpPost.setEntity(stringEntity);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            int code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (code == 200) {
                HttpEntity respEntity = response.getEntity();
                String result = EntityUtils.toString(respEntity);
                Resp resp = GSON.fromJson(result, Resp.class);
                if (!resp.getError() && 
                 !resp.getResult().getUser().getIsBlocked()) {
                    return resp;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180130</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <groupId>prob2</groupId>
    <artifactId>prob2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.devcolibri.mavenjavafxapp.MainApp</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Ошибка из консоли

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpEntity
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:927)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)
        at com.devcolibri.mavenjavafxapp.MainApp.start(MainApp.java:22)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.HttpEntity
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 22 more
Exception running application com.devcolibri.mavenjavafxapp.MainApp
```

Сборка проекта

Project Structure -> Artifactc
[image: Artifacts JavaFX]

[image: Artifacts Output Layout]

Далее Build-> Build Artifacts-> Build

Comment: Полный текст ошибки добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: По характеру ошибки, скорее всего проблема с получением ресурса в jar, присоединяюсь к комментарию про полный текст ошибки

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev, как можно получить текст ошибки?

Comment: @ДмитрийМилютин открыть консоль, перейти в каталог с jar-файлом, выполнить `java -jar <filename.jar>` и скопировать выхлоп.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Добавил текст ошибки

Comment: Как собираете jar файл?

Comment: @Maxim Добавил в описании сборку проекта

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда IDEA запускает вашу программу, она обеспечивает присутствие необходимых ей зависимостей в CLASSPATH. Когда вы запускаете её сами, вы этого не делаете и программа падает, так как не может найти httpclient-4.5.5.jar, в частности.

Самый простой выход из этой ситуации - собрать *fat jar*, включающий классы как самой программы, так и всех её зависимостей. Сделать это можно, немного расширив pom.xml:

```
<project ... >
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Теперь при сборке будет создавать два jar-файла - обычный с именем вида `<имя>-<версия>.jar` и *толстый* с именем вида `<имя>-<версия>-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

Второй способ - это поставлять приложение вместе с jar-файлами зависимостей. Для этого надо, во-первых, обеспечить добавление секции `Class-Path:` в манифест. Сделать это можно добавление в pom.xml

```
<project ... >
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Во-вторых, после выполнения сборки нужно выполнить команду `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies`, по которой Maven скопирует все зависимости в target/dependency. После этого можно копировать jar-файл программы и jar-файлы зависимостей в один рабочий каталог и запускать программу.

Comment: Попробовал первый способ. Мне кажется я неправильно собирают проект. Добавил, как я это делаю в самом вопросе. В результате сборки у меня получается папка с названием проекта. В ней  папка "bundles" и есть jar проекта. В папке "bundles" лежит еще один jar проекта и папка с названием проекта. В папке лежат "app" и "runtime" папки + куча файлов среди которых .exe проекта.

Comment: Для сборки используйте "mvn package", потом "mvn dependency:copy-dependencies".

Comment: @Maxim Нужно было установить Maven и настроить окружение и все собралось. Спасибо большое. 
Вопрос появился один, если мне надо будет запустить эту программу на другом ПК, мне нужно там установить так же Maven? или хватит JVM?

Comment: @ДмитрийМилютин Maven - это сборщик, он может быть нужен только в процессе компиляции. На этапе выполнения программы он не нужен.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev т.е. мне нужно скопировать все содержимое папки "target" и перенести на другой пк?

Comment: Ни в коем случае! Там куча мусора от этапа сборки. Используйте только необходимые jar-файлы.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev спасибо большое за помощь!)