# Ошибка: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again

Tags: java

Скомпилировал проект при помощи Maven при запуске jar файла через терминал выдает ошибку:

> ```
> Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/Connector
> ```

Суть в том, что в Еклипсе проект запускается и успешно работает.

Вот код главного класса:

```
EventServer 
{


        public static void main(String[] args)

        {

            Server server = new Server();

            ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);

            connector.setPort(8081);

            server.addConnector(connector);



            // Setup the basic application "context" for this application at "/"

            // This is also known as the handler tree (in jetty speak)

            ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);

            context.setContextPath("/");

            server.setHandler(context);



            try

            {

                // Initialize javax.websocket layer

                ServerContainer wscontainer = WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.configureContext(context);



                // Add WebSocket endpoint to javax.websocket layer

                wscontainer.addEndpoint(EventSocket.class);



                server.start();

                server.dump(System.err);

                server.join();

            }

            catch (Throwable t)

            {

                t.printStackTrace(System.err);

            }

        }

    }
```

В pom.xml прописаны зависимости:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>rr</groupId>
  <artifactId>rr</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>


    <dependencies>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax-websocket-server-impl</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.12.v20180830</version>
</dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>


</project>
```

С чем может быть связана эта проблема?

Comment: Дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка invoking method при запуске jar](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/856878/204271)

Comment: К сожалению добавление указанных строк не решило проблему

Comment: Проблема как я понимаю в расположении второго класса программы, при компиляции оно не может найти, я пробовал запустить проэкт по сл. команде java -classpath D: \ myprogram; D: \ myprogram \ lib \ supportLib.jar org.mypackage.HelloWorld  он заработал

Comment: Судя по ошибке, проблема в том, что JVM не может найти javax-websocket-server-impl-9.4.12.v20180830.jar в CLASSPATH.

Comment: Да, но я не понимаю почему, данный класс лежит в попке рядом с основным классом

Comment: Это не класс, а jar. Нахождение дополнительных jar-файлов в одном каталоге с jar-файлом вашей программы не делает их классы автоматически доступными в CLASSPATH. Как я уже писал в дубликате вашего вопроса, надо либо перечислить их в манифесте, либо упаковать в один толстый jar.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь разобрался