# Как прописать мейн класс в pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass></mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

я знаю что в мейн нужно прописывать package в таком роде com.sdsds.Main
но что если проект не содержит в себе пакетов?как тогда указать мейн класс,чтобы из консоли можно было запустить jar

Comment: Боюсь что никак. Любой `jar` который Вы хотите запускать должен иметь класс с методом `main`.

Answer (score 2):

Просто

```
<mainClass>Main</mainClass>
```

Comment: мой мейн класс имеет имя Bt

Comment: прописал в pom.xml Bt и получил вот такую ошибку

Comment: Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/telegram/telegrambots/meta/exceptions/TelegramApiRequestException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)

Comment: Ошибка говорит о том, что в  CLASSPATH нет зависимости telegrambots-meta-4.1.jar

Comment: надо в pom.xml прописать зависимости для компиляции?

Comment: [Можно и прописать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/857013/204271).