# Проблема с .jar "No main manifest attribute"

Tags: java, maven, jar, атрибуты, manifest

Ситуация такая: Есть maven проект, в нем несколько модулей (так нужно), есть класс с методом main(), в котором вызываются определенные методы, но это не суть. Я мало знаком с maven'ом, но мне нужно создать запускаемый jar файл этого проекта. Я работаю в intellij idea, чтобы создать jar я выполняю maven: clean + install, у меня создалось 3 папки target в каждом модуле. Метод main() находиться в модуле calc-console.

В консоли я выполняю `java -jar calc-console-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` и получаю no main manifest attribute in calc-console-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.

Может у меня проблема с pom.xml? Родительский pom я не трогал, а во внутренних pom я указывал только зависимости между модулями (не считая того, что уже было изначально сгенерировано).

Comment: a compile делали?

Comment: @Dred а разве clean + install не включает в себя compile? Если сделать просто compile, то jar не создается

Comment: У меня точно такая же ошибка
no main manifest attribute, in first.jar В pom.xml указывал <mainClass>Main</mainClass> [![введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAQJt.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAQJt.png) Пока не нашел решение...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JVM понятия не имеет, в каком именно классе есть метод `main`, [ей надо подсказать](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html). В тексте ошибки даже написано, как это сделать: нужно в манифесте определить атрибут `Main-Class`, в значении которого будет полное имя класса. Чтобы Maven сгенерировал этот атрибут автоматически, нужно добавить в pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  ...

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>ЗДЕСЬ ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ ИМЯ КЛАССА</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Мой класс с методом main() называется App. т.е. по вашему примеру я сделал <mainClass>App</mainClass>. Но теперь получаю Error: Could not find or load main class App в консоли, при выполнении java -jar calc-console-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: @Artem просто App? Пакет не используете?

Comment: Если с пакетом (com.App), то в консоли бросается Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.CalcImpl

Comment: А это уже другая проблема и [вот к ней решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/857013/204271).

Answer (score 0):

у меня была такая же проблемма я сделал так в правом верхнем углу есть выбор файла у меня стоял: mysql-connector-j, спустя 2 как я почитал предыдущий ответ на этот вопрос и попытался также не получилось я переключил файл на main и у меня все заработало