# Как запустить jar на javafx в консоли?

Tags: java, javafx, консоль, jar, запуск

Я написал программу на javafx. Как мне открыть в консоли jar?

При попытке написать java -jar FunctionDrawer.jar, выводит:

```
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class Main
    java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Preview features are not enabled for Main (class file version 56.65535). 
Try running with '--enable-preview'
```

java --enable-preview -jar FunctionDrawer.jar

```
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
```

java --module-path C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-12.0.1\lib --add-modules=javafx.controls --enable-preview -jar FunctionDrawer.jar

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Files\Java\javafx-sdk-12.0.1\lib
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files\Java\javafx-sdk-12.0.1\lib
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что в названии папки `Program files` есть пробел. Из-за этого ява думала, что путь к файлу заканчивается на слове *Program*. Как сказал Сергей Горностаев, необходимо заключить путь в кавычки. Есть ещё вариант перенести библиотеку `javafx` в другую папку.

Comment: Заключить путь в кавычки.

Comment: Это не ответ на изначальный вопрос. А менять смысл вопроса правками после того, как получен ответ - это плохая, осуждаемая сообществом практика.

Comment: Ответ. Потому что в этом была проблема.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия то есть ошибка `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Preview features are not enabled for Main` у вас появлялась из-за пробела в пути, и всё нормально запустится даже без ключа `--enable-preview`?

Comment: @Hivemaster перед тем, как задать вопрос, я пробовал написать это, в конечном счёте ошибка оказалась в другом. И да, в моих же интересах поставить галочку на первый ответ и получить 2 балла репутации, но я этого делать не буду, потому что я честный.

Answer (score 1):

Ваша программа компилировалась с ключом `--enable-preview`, а значит и запускаться должна тоже с ним.

Comment: А как это правильно написать в консоли? И можете ещё сказать, что делает этот ключ? И он как-то автоматически записался intellij ide(ей), я его не писал.

Comment: `java --enable-preview -jar some.jar` Этот ключ включает [новые возможности языка](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/12), которые уже реализованы, но ещё не утверждены.

Comment: я попробовал, дополнил вопрос.

Comment: А это уже другая проблема, связанная с отсутствием javafx в classpath. Почитать о способах решения можно [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/857013/204271) и [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/911147/204271).

Comment: Не понял, я же там пишу библиотеку с модулями fx.

Comment: Где "там" пишите?

Comment: --module-path C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-12.0.1\lib --add-modules=javafx.controls

Comment: И? Где вы эти ключи вводите?

Comment: Ой, понятия не имею. Надо же модули подключить. Там написано JavaFX runtime components are missing

Comment: Если вы не знаете, что именно делаете, то мне тем более этого знать неоткуда. К тому же, мы вышли за дозволенные пределы переписки в комментариях.