# "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError maven

Tags: java, maven, gson

Пытаюсь собрать jar'ник.
Делаю это через maven
pom.xml выглядит следющим образом:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>xmlReader</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlReader</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/stax/stax-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>stax</groupId>
            <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Компиляция проходит корректно. Jar файл создается, но при его запуске:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Выдаёт ошибку `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson`

Структура проекта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Содержимое папки target:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка invoking method при запуске jar](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/856878/204271)

Comment: Такая ошибка возникает потому что класслоадер не может найти код соответствующий ссылке.

Comment: Roman C, знаешь как исправить?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev попробовал сделать те действия, которые описаны в ответе на данный вопрос, не помогли. single jar собрал, собрал jar'ник с зависимостями... обновленный pom кинул в вопрос