# Не запускается .jar (JAVAFX) в ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, javafx, intellij-idea, jar

Проблема с запуском .jar файла в Ubuntu 18.04 x64. Компилирую jar-файл проекта JavaFX в Windows в среде IntelliJ IDEA, а далее копирую на Ubuntu. На винде все прекрасно работает, и насколько я помню, .jar - кроссплатформенный. Но, если я его запускаю из терминала командой `java -jar` под Ubuntu, то выдает ошибку:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class sample.Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как с этим быть.

Comment: какая Java на ubuntu? openJDK?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка invoking method при запуске jar](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/856878/204271)

Comment: @Komdosh openJDK

Comment: @Komdosh Я не тот JDK использую? Да, кстати, приложение компилировалось с использованием jdk 1.8. В Ubuntu устанавливал openJDK с помощью терминала.

Answer (score 1):

Обратите внимание на вторую строчку `Caused by`. Она вам говорит, что загрузчик классов не смог найти определение класса javafx.application.Application, который по-умолчанию лежит в библиотеке `jfxrt.jar` Скорее всего в вашем дистрибутиве OpenJDK она просто отсутствует.

На зарубежном StackOverflow уже был похожий вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34243982/why-is-javafx-is-not-included-in-openjdk-8-on-ubuntu-wily-15-10

Там ответили, что в Ubuntu есть отдельный пакет **openjfx**, который включает JavaFX. Его можно установить следующей командой:

`sudo apt-get install openjfx`